# How to indent the equation number to the right?

Tags: equations, math-operators

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
\delta{\mathbf{E_e} = \sum \limits_{I=1}^{M} \emph{B}_{LI} \eta_I
\label{eq:fortythree}
\end{equation}
```

I have couple of questions based on my example below. How can I make letter 'B' bold and italicized at the same time. Also, the equation number is displayed just besides the equation rather than to the right as in case of my previous equations. See figure below for your reference

Output

[image]

Required

[image]

Comment: You have a stray left brace `{` after `\delta` that, when removed, will remedy the equation number alignment.  Also, bold math symbols are typically not italicized.  You should use `\mathbf{B}` to get an upright bold `B`.  Also, the default greek fonts are not emboldened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

the equation number was a syntax error extra `{` (don't ignore error messages!)

You can get bold math italic using `\bm` from the package of the same name.

Also:  don't use `\emph` in math mode, and you do not need `\limits` here.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
\delta\bm{E}_e = \sum_{I=1}^{M} \bm{B}_{LI} \bm{\eta}_I
\label{eq:fortythree}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```